# R: How to add a column with a randomly chosen value from each row of a matrix?

Tags: r, random

I'll preface this by saying I'm an R noob and that I think this may have an easy solution, but I'm struggling to find it.

I've got a matrix with 2 columns and 1,000 rows. Keeping the rows fixed, I'd like to create a new variable that randomly chooses one of the elements from the 2 columns. For example making a simple matrix:

```
        matrix(c(1,1,4,6,1,3,2,1,1,7), ncol=2)

        [,1] [,2] [,3]
  [1,]    1    3    3
  [2,]    1    2    1  
  [3,]    4    1    4
  [4,]    6    1    1
  [5,]    1    7    7
```

In the simplified matrix above, the 3rd column (which I just added by hand) just contains a random element from either of the prior columns in the corresponding row. My question is, how would I create such a variable in R? I don't necessarily need it to be created within the matrix itself either.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8):

```
t <- matrix(c(1,1,4,6,1,3,2,1,1,7), ncol=2)
cbind(t,apply(t,1,function(x) sample(x,size=1)))

      [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    3    1
[2,]    1    2    2
[3,]    4    1    4
[4,]    6    1    1
[5,]    1    7    1
```

Comment: @DWin, yes, a bit, 48 = nchar(my_variant) < 77 = nchar(your_variant) =)

Comment: @tex, you are welcome, come back to stackoveflow.com when need to solve smth. programming =)

Comment: @teh, if you think any of the answers solved your problem, please click the gray tick just under your favorite answer.

Comment: @DWin: more compact yet: `cbind(t,apply(t,1,sample,1))`

Comment: @Joshua Ulrich: I've clearly lost the compactness competition here. But I'm still winning on time performance.

Comment: @DWin, good reply about time performance. yes, in fact, apply in my solution is bottleneck. So, it is draw: you are winning time performance, me - compactness performance :)

Comment: @Joshua Ulrich:  I think Max's is also more clear which counts for a lot in programming. My favorite, the one with conjoined logical indices,  requires that you mentally think about unfolding and refolding a matrix. Might be helpful to someone seeking to understand matrix operations, but still a bit of a mind-twister.

Answer (score 5):

```
cbind(mat, mat[cbind( 1:NROW(mat), sample(1:2, NROW(mat), replace=TRUE) ) ] )

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    3    1
[2,]    1    2    2
[3,]    4    1    4
[4,]    6    1    1
[5,]    1    7    1
```

Tha above method uses sampling from 1:2 along one column of an indexing matrix. Below is a method that samples along the first column and then picks the remaining rows from the second column. These might be faster if these structures were large or if many replicates were needed in simulation exercises:

```
 idx<-sample(c(TRUE,FALSE), prod(dim(mat))/2, replace=TRUE) # a 5 element logic vector
 cbind( mat, mat[ c(idx, !idx)] )  # using the idx and negation of the idx
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    3    1
[2,]    1    2    2
[3,]    4    1    1
[4,]    6    1    1
[5,]    1    7    7
```