# R: How to randomly sample from each row of matrix into new column but only switch columns with rng

Tags: r, matrix, random

I'm new to R and I'm having difficulty finding answers to my question. I found this question that was asked years ago which leads me in the right direction: 
[R: How to add a column with a randomly chosen value from each row of a matrix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8046428/r-how-to-add-a-column-with-a-randomly-chosen-value-from-each-row-of-a-matrix?newreg=e67f7f94270542cfa39bcd27dfc42310)

The difference in mine is that I want to build the third column with conditional sampling while randomly choosing which one to start with. If I have two columns in my matrix, I want to 1. randomly pick which column to start sampling from and 2. only switch columns if I run an rng and it falls below a certain threshold. I want to be able to run the rng before sampling each row.

I haven't been able to find much in the way of help and that might be a consequence of just not knowing what to look for. Thank you.

Updated with example:

This code (from the link) generates a third column by randomly picking an element from row 1 (either from column 1 or column 2) and does so for all the rows.

```
t <- matrix(c(1,1,4,6,1,3,2,1,1,7), ncol=2)
cbind(t,apply(t,1,function(x) sample(x,size=1)))

      [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    3    1
[2,]    1    2    2
[3,]    4    1    4
[4,]    6    1    1
[5,]    1    7    1
```

I want to be able to generate a matrix that builds column 3 by randomly choosing column 1 or 2 at first and only samples from that column. And after each row is built, run an rng. If the rng generates a number below a threshold, I want it to switch the column it is building from.

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    3    3
[2,]    1    2    2
[3,]    4    1    4      (supposedly rng meets threshold here and switches from col 2 to 1)
[4,]    6    1    6
[5,]    1    7    1
```

Comment: Please provide an example, like in the question you referenced. Also I'm a little confused: if you are sampling row-wise, what does it mean to "randomly pick which column to start sampling from"?  It would help if you illustrated using an example.

Comment: I updated with an example. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

we can set the range for our sample

```
x <- 1:10
sample(x[x >  5])
sample(x[x <  10]
```

Answer (score 0):

We first randomly choose the default column

```
def <- sample(1:2, 1)  # set default
```

We can write a simple function that takes two arguments: a vector `x` (should be length 2), and a threshold (here I set the default threshold at 0.2).  If the random number generated by `runif()` is less than the threshold, pick element `3 - def` from `x` (so we switch the column), else use the default.

```
sample_row <- function(x, thr = .2) x[ifelse(runif(1) <= thr, 3 - def, def)]
```

Run that through `apply`, and `cbind`. In the example, `def` is 2, and row 2 has been "switched":

```
cbind(t, apply(t, 1, sample_row))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    3    3
# [2,]    1    2    1
# [3,]    4    1    1
# [4,]    6    1    1
# [5,]    1    7    7
```